# Resolve Entire Application Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an application with a simple main template with a header and a footer, like so

```
<section style="margin-bottom:70px">
   <nav-menu></nav-menu>
</section>
<section>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
<section>
   <foot></foot>
</section>
```

The router outlet has resolvers on it to stop the UI from paining until an Api call is complete. This leads to the UI only having the header an footer viewable until the Api comes back. Is there way to resolve on the other components as well? Maybe like a shared service that the other components subscribe to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this:

1) You could build a service with a `loaded` or similar flag that is set by the resolver. Then add an `*ngIf` on the other components that prevent them from displaying until the `loaded` flag is set.

2) Build an interim component with a single router outlet. Move the code you currently have into a child route of that interim router outlet. Then you could set the resolver on that child route.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

main.component.html

```
<section style="margin-bottom:70px">
   <nav-menu></nav-menu>
</section>
<section>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
<section>
   <foot></foot>
</section>
```

The route configuration would define a route to the main component and there would be the route resolver. Your current route would be a child route of this route.

Comment: Thanks Deborah, the 2nd option seems more elegant. What would the implementation look like?